# XMonad confirmation when restarting

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm a Haskell beginner and I'm using xmonad. I'm trying to make it prompt me before quitting as I occasionally hit mod+q by accident. I've found two ways of doing that, but I must be doing something wrong because neither of them work for me:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120298
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.xmonad/11699

Here's my xmonad.hs:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Gnome
import XMonad.Actions.Plane
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
import System.IO(Handle, hPutStrLn)
import System.Exit
import Control.Monad
import XMonad
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
import XMonad.Util.Dmenu
import XMonad.Util.Run

workspaces' = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

quit_confirm :: X ()
quit_confirm = do
  let m = "confirm restart"
  s <- dmenu [m]
  when (m == s) (spawn "xmonad --restart")

conf_quit = do
  response <- runProcessWithInput "dmenu" ["-p", "Quit?"] "yes\nno\n"
  when (response == "yes") (spawn "xmonad --restart")

main = do
        dzen2Pipe <- spawnPipe "dzen2 -w 1200 -xs 1 -ta l -fn '-*-terminus-*-*-*-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-*-*' -bg black -fg #d3d7cf "
        dzen2Right <- spawnPipe "~/.xmonad/status-dzen.sh"
        startupProgs <- spawnPipe "~/.xmonad/startups.sh"
        xmonad $ defaultConfig
             {
             workspaces = workspaces'
             , manageHook = manageHook' <+> manageHook defaultConfig
             , modMask = mod4Mask
             , terminal = "gnome-terminal"
     , layoutHook = layoutHook'
         , logHook = logHook' dzen2Pipe
             }
            `additionalKeysP`
               [ -- Lock Screen
                ("M-S-l",    spawn "gnome-screensaver-command -l")
                -- Sleep
                , ("M-S-;",   spawn "gnome-screensaver-command -l; pmi action suspend")
                -- wireless
                , ("M-S-C-w", spawn "~/.xmonad/wireless.sh")
                -- 1 screen reconf
                , ("M-S-C-1", spawn "~/.xmonad/1-screen.sh")
                -- 2 screen reconf
                , ("M-S-C-2", spawn "~/.xmonad/2-screen.sh")
                -- confirm for quit
                , ("M-q", conf_quit)
                ]
             `additionalKeys`
             M.toList (planeKeys mod4Mask GConf Finite)

layoutHook' = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig

logHook' = dynamicLogWithPP . dzenPP'

dzenPP' h = defaultPP
            {
            ppOutput = hPutStrLn h
            }

manageHook' = composeAll
  [ className =? "Pidgin" --> doShift "1" ,
    className =? "Firefox" --> doShift "2" ,
    className =? "Thunderbird" --> doShift "3" ,
    className =? "OpenOffice.org 3.2" --> doShift "4",
    manageDocks ]
```

Thanks!

Edit: the menu is displayed, but spawn process doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You named it `conf_quit`, but it does a restart. Do you want it to quit or restart after a successful confirmation?

Comment: I went through both, but it doesn't perform the spawn process. I'm starting to think that my problem comes from somewhere else since the code works for other people.

Comment: What exactly happens? What makes you think the `spawn` isn't happening? What happens when you bind the key to something more obvious than a spawn, say, an actual quit? Can you check that your xmonad executable is in xmonad's `PATH` (which may differ from your terminal's `PATH` and your console's `PATH`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers others gave missed that `dmenu` seems to add an extra whitespace to the end of the string it returns. You just need to do the following and it works for me:

```
confirm :: String -> X () -> X ()
confirm m f = do
  result <- dmenu [m]
  when (init result == m) f
```

And then, as @mariop suggested use either

```
confirm "Restart" $ spawn "xmonad --recompile && xmonad --restart"
```

or

```
confirm "Exit" $ io (exitWith ExitSuccess)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the key binding to

```
("M-q", confirm "Confirm restart?" $ restart "xmonad" True)
```

And add a generic confirmation action that uses dmenu

```
confirm :: String -> X () -> X ()
confirm msg f = do
    a <- dmenu [msg,"y","n"]
    when (a=="y") f
```

Comment: Hi, I tried, but still didn't work. The menu is shown, but the doesn't seem to be executed and I can't find anything relevant in my .xsession-errors either

Comment: I had problems sometimes while trying to restart xmonad and the solution was to restart the X session instead of reloading Xmonad (for example, restart gdm). Now I tried by myself and my code is working on xmonad 0.10-2 (debian package).

Answer (score 0):

You say you want a quit confirm but your code does a restart confirm.
If this is restart that you want, I tested and `quit_confirm` works.

What you most likely miss is the recompilation of xmonad to see your new configuration.
Try this:

```
quit_confirm :: X ()
quit_confirm = do
  let m = "confirm restart"
  s <- dmenu [m]
  when (m == s) (spawn "xmonad recompile && xmonad --restart")
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately it didn't work. The menu is displayed, but it doesn't seem to execute the spawn process. I'm thinking that it might be wither a hook that I missed or an x miss-configuration.

Comment: Try spawning something else that you know works such as wireless.sh.

Comment: It's the same and .xsession-errors doesn't seem to have anything useful in it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following module, which doesn't require `dmenu` to be installed:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- |
-- Module      :  XMonad.Prompt
-- Copyright   :  (C) 2015 Antoine Beaupré
-- License     :  BSD3
--
-- Maintainer  :  Antoine Beaupré <anarcat@debian.org>
-- Stability   :  unstable
-- Portability :  unportable
--
-- A module for setting up simple confirmation prompts for keybindings.
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
module XMonad.Prompt.ConfirmPrompt (confirmPrompt
                                    -- * Usage
                                    -- $usage
                                    , module XMonad.Prompt
                                    -- * Use case: confirming exit
                                    -- $tip
                                    , EnterPrompt
                                    ) where

import XMonad (X)
import XMonad.Prompt (XPConfig, XPrompt, showXPrompt, mkXPrompt, mkComplFunFromList)

{- $usage

This module makes it easy to add a confirmation prompt for specific
actions. Instead of just running the action, a simple confirmation
prompt will be created using 'XMonad.Prompt' primitives. The action
will then run normally if the user confirms.
-}

{- $tip
This should be used something like this:

> ...
> , ((modm , xK_l), confirmPrompt defaultXPConfig "exit" $ io (exitWith ExitSuccess))
> ...
-}

{- | Customized 'XPrompt' prompt that will ask to confirm the given string -}
data EnterPrompt = EnterPrompt String
instance XPrompt EnterPrompt where
    showXPrompt (EnterPrompt n) = "Confirm " ++ n ++ " (esc/ENTER)"

{- | Prompt the user to confirm a given action. We offer no completion
     and simply ask to confirm (ENTER) or cancel (ESCAPE). The actual key
     handling is done by mkXPrompt.-}
confirmPrompt :: XPConfig -> String -> X() -> X()
confirmPrompt config app func = mkXPrompt (EnterPrompt app) config (mkComplFunFromList []) $ const func
```

Install this in a `~/.xmonad/lib/XMonad/Prompt` directory and enjoy!

(I [submitted](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2015-February/014540.html) this to the XMonad mailing list and I'm waiting for feedback...)